# Passing specific search parameters into results page

Tags: solspace, supersearch

Hey I am going to be using Super search and am wondering how easy it is to pass a parameter to the results page. For example I will have a site with realtors on it and I want to have a link at the bottom of each page to go to a results page that shows just that realtors listings. Can I easily set that up? I've looked through the Docs but nothing jumped out at me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as I read in the document http://www.solspace.com/docs/super_search/results/

> The Super_Search:Results tag displays the entry results from a search
>   query. And since search queries in the URI (and from POST searches)
>   are human-readable
>   (template_group/template/search&keywords=bird&summary=is+the+word),
>   users can bookmark result pages, along with many other benefits.
>   Searches can be performed in a variety of ways:

I think you can do it easily by using {exp:super_search:results} as mention in the document.

I hope this will help you , if you need more help tell me.

Regard's.

Comment: Thanks, I've read that too. I'm just unsure as to how to pass the search from one template without using a search form. So if it's just a link how to get the results page to show the proper results.

Comment: as I understand , use a test form in a test template , do the search you want this will give you a URL with the query string variables  this URL is the link you want.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. I'll give it a try and report back.